# Why is $\gimel(\kappa)>\kappa$?

Tags: logic, set-theory

I want to prove that $\gimel(\kappa)=\kappa^{\text{cof}(\kappa)}>\kappa$, by using [König's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)).

So I basically said this: $$\kappa^{\text{cof}(\kappa)}=\prod_{i<\text{cof}(\kappa)}\kappa$$ and $$\kappa=\sum_{i<\text{cof}(\kappa)}f(i),$$ where $f:\text{cof}(\kappa)\leftrightarrow x$ with $x$ cofinal in $\kappa$. Then this would follow directly from König's theorem. I'm not sure about the last equality, but my reasoning would be: $$\begin{align*}\kappa&=\bigcup_{i<\text{cof}(\kappa)}f(i)\\&=\text{card}\left(\bigcup_{i<\text{cof}(\kappa)}f(i)\right)\\&\leq\text{card}\left(\bigcup_{i<\text{cof}(\kappa)}f(i)\times\{i\}\right)\\&=\sum_{i<\text{cof}(\kappa)}f(i)\end{align*}$$ I'm not sure about the inequality in the other direction. I feel like it should be trivial, but the disjoint union used in the definition of the sum is throwing me of. Can someone help me for that?

Edit: My first equation is not true I think, that sort of manipulation only works when the exponent is strictly smaller than the cofinality of the base, I think.

Comment: Which equation is 'your first equation' that you think isn't true?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen $\kappa^{\text{cof}(\kappa)}=\prod_{i<\text{cof}(\kappa)}\kappa$

Comment: That is true. The definition of both sides is "the number of functions from $\operatorname{cof} \kappa$ to $\kappa$"

Comment: Ah yes you are right, I was confused with another argument where one restricts the image of functions, but that doesn't happen here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following theorem is what you need

> If $\kappa_i$ are nonzero cardinals for $i\in I,$ and $I$ is infinite, then $\sum_{i\in I}\kappa_i = |I| \cdot\sup_{i\in I}\kappa_i.$
>
> *Proof*: Since $\kappa_i\geq 1,$ we have $\sum_i \kappa_i\ge |I|,$ and $\sum_i \kappa_i\ge \kappa_i$ for each $i$ so $\sum_i \kappa_i \ge \sup_i \kappa_i.$ For the other direction, $\sum_i \kappa_i \le \sum_i \sup_j \kappa_j= |I|\cdot \sup_j \kappa_j.$

Comment: That was indeed the missing piece.